# Azure SDK .NET Authenticate issues(ServicePrincipalLoginInformation should contain a valid ClientId information)

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, azure-authentication

I`m trying to manage an Azure Elastic Pool, and login following the Microsoft example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication)
but I cannot use the **SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal**.
I get the following error:

> {"Cannot communicate with server. ServicePrincipalLoginInformation should contain a valid ClientId information."}

And here is my code:

```
string clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("4a8ca462-413d- ...etc.etc");
string appSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("2ri-a1wZJzPy.C ... etc.etc");
string tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("d7cc8849-2174- ... etc.etc.");

var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                    .FromServicePrincipal(clientId, appSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var azure = Azure
        .Configure()
        .Authenticate(credentials)
        .WithSubscription("x1dfe0t2-41b5-etc.etc.");
```

I did try to look at the line of code in GIT, because it`s an open source, but could not find why clientId is null ...

Fluent version 1.37.1 and .NET Core

Comment: Please edit your question and share your environment variables.

Comment: Are your environment variable names actually GUIDs? Maybe dump the 3 variables to output after you populate them to make sure you're getting the right values.

Comment: Beside the clientSecret, they are guids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the exception information and [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/src/ResourceManagement/ResourceManager/Authentication/AzureCredentials.cs), it seems that you supplied the blank client id.

[image]

Please check if the result from `string clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("4a8ca462-413d- ...etc.etc")` is null.

For example, set the name of client id as AZURE_CLIENT_ID and set the value with guid. Then get the client id in C# with variable name.

```
string clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID");
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Pamela, that was the problem. I am stupid and now I know it